# How to reduce the sourness of homemade frozen yogurt?

Tags: flavor, yogurt, frozen-yogurt

I like to make homemade yogurt and I am experimenting with timing to get my yogurt to be not so sour but still completely set. Yogurt is, by definition, quite acidic since that is what sets the protein in the first place.

Commercial frozen yogurts seem to be much milder than I can achieve at home. I assume this is because they are using thickeners rather than 100% yogurt. Because they aren't as sour you can find frozen yogurts of almost any flavor.

Since my yogurt is so sour I am more limited in what flavors work well with it. A sour chocolate frozen yogurt does not make my tongue happy. I have in the past made a variety of citrus flavors with and without ginger. These are tasty but I'm getting tired of them.

How can I make my frozen yogurt less sour so that more flavors work well with it?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I assume that in commercial yoghurt, there is a lot of sugar added. Did you add any?

Comment: @Mien - I did. Quite a bit in fact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overly sour yogurt is a sign of inconsistent inoculation

Check the type of culture you are using, and ensure you are keeping the yogurt above 37C for more than six hours. The yogurt should finish as a solid lump that resists pouring, not a thick liquid, or a lumpy paste

Pouring off the whey and straining the yogurt makes it more creamy and taste sweeter

Thickeners are not required, just complete inoculation

For sweet yogurt dishes I mostly use sour berries (blackberry, raspberry etc) so it is expected to be somewhat sour anyway

Comment: This was perfect. I used my sous-vide controller to make my yogurt instead of the old yogurt maker and it turned out thicker and much less sour. I made blueberry frozen yogurt and it is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of refined sugar which can be very strong try other sources of sweetness. For example, very ripe natural canteloupe and honey. Adding a spice or herb (e.g. cinnamon) creates a nice finish.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas- I'll try the melons in the summer when they are in season.