# "Overly sour yogurt is a sign of inconsistent inoculation" - What is inoculation?

Tags: yogurt

From here: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/13533/6168

> Overly sour yogurt is a sign of inconsistent inoculation

From: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inoculation

> The act or an instance of inoculating, especially the introduction of an antigenic substance or vaccine into the body to produce immunity to a specific disease.

What is that quote talking about? How can "inconsistent inoculation" be prevented?

Comment: The definition from free dictionary is good. It's the same when introducing a culture to a growth medium. In this case, three strains of bacteria and the yogurt. This culture is an inoculation because it controls which strains grow in the yogurt. Without inoculation, you have no control over the process and the results which could be anywhere from perfect yogurt to deadly results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, *inoculation* refers to the introduction of yoghurt bacteria ([lactic acid bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactobacillales)) that transform the milk into yoghurt.

If anything goes wrong - from unclean conditions that let other bacteria grow to unfavourable temperatures that inhibit the proper growth of your desired lactobacillae - you speak of improper inoculation.

The effects on taste and possibly food-safety have been discussed in your linked posts.

So work in a clean environment, use a good strain of bacteria and maintain the recommended temperature range to prevent this.